# Is the source code for Universal Membership Provider (System.Web.Providers) available?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

Is the source code for Universal Membership Provider available? Is the project open source? To be more clear, I'm talking about the System.Web.Providers.dll, available from Nuget: (http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Providers/)

That DLL doesn't seem to be part of the [ASP.NET source code hosted on Codeplex.](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/) But maybe it's available from some other place?

Comment: If it is not available you may want to use a decompiler to get the source from the dll.

Answer (score 0):

A quick review of the first few pages of results from a [Google search for "Microsoft ASP.NET Universal Providers" "source code"](https://www.google.com/#q=%22Microsoft+ASP.NET+Universal+Providers%22+%22source+code%22) shows no source code or links to source code. Additionally, there isn't a link to any source code on the NuGet Gallery Page for [Microsoft ASP.NET Universal Providers](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Providers), and the [License Terms](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/eula/system.web.providers-1.0-eula.htm) seem to prohibit disclosure or distribution of source code.

It's a safe bet to say the project is closed source, but if you still *really* want the source code, you have to options:

1. [Ask Microsoft for it](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Providers/ContactOwners). It's not likely to work, but hey -- who knows?
2. Violate the [License Terms](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/eula/system.web.providers-1.0-eula.htm) and decompile the DLL with a tool like [.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) ($$) or [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) (free). For obvious reasons, I don't condone going this route.

Good luck!